# 2 Controllers com a mesma API

Tags: angularjs

meu conhecimento em angular é pouco ainda e tenho dúvidas até um pouco tontas, mas vamos lá hehe. Preciso de um controller que mostre os registros recentes (8 ultimos) e outro com uma lista geral (de 20 itens). Veja meu raciocínio abaixo.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('recentesCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.loading = true;
     $scope.limitM = 8;
     $http.get("http://www.folhacar.com.br/api/listAnuncios?revenda_id=528&cnpj=13733235000134")
     .success(function (data) {$scope.nomes = data;}).finally(function() {
     $scope.loading = false;
      });

app.controller('listaCompletaCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $scope.loading = true;
     $scope.limitM = 20;
     $http.get("http://www.folhacar.com.br/api/listAnuncios?revenda_id=528&cnpj=13733235000134")
     .success(function (data2) {$scope.nomes2 = data2;}).finally(function() {
     $scope.loading = false;
     });
});
```

Com toda a certeza nao esta certo, como posso fazer isso com eficiência sendo que os 2 controllers estao utilizando a mesma API, mesma url e tudo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um **service** para organizar/reutilizar o seu código, por exemplo:

```
var MyService = angular.module('MyService', [])
.service('TestServ', function () {
    this.methodAPI = function (limit) { 
          $scope.limitM = limit;
          $scope.loading = true;
          $http.get("http://www.folhacar.com.br/api/listAnuncios?revenda_id=528&cnpj=13733235000134")
     .success(function (data) {$scope.nomes = data;}).finally(function() {
     $scope.loading = false;
};

});

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['MyService']);
  app.controller('recentesCtrl', function($scope, $http, TestServ) {
      $scope.callService = function () {
        TesteServ.methodAPI(8);
    }   

});

  app.controller('listaCompletaCtrl', function($scope, $http, TestServ) {
      $scope.callService = function () {
        TesteServ.methodAPI(20);
    }     
});
```

Comment: Por alguma razão não funciona :(

Comment: Ocorre qual erro ?

Esse conteúdo fala sobre service >> [Link](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/services-in-angularjs-simplified-with-examples)